# Cannot install package using pip

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am new to installing python packages using pip and am running into trouble. I am trying to install the library "mlfinlab" using pip and running it in Anaconda/Jupyter Notebooks. When i type "pip install mlfinlab" into my terminal i get the following message at the end:

```
Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I'm not sure if that error message is relevant but thought I'd include it anyways.

I had tried to then run a Jupyter Notebook and import mlfinlab but was given the messsage that there were no modules by that name.

I have already tried running:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

in a Jupyter Notebook and then typing the output of that into my command line along with "-m pip install mlfinlab" which did not seem to work either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Cannot+uninstall+It+is+a+distutils+installed+project+and+thus+we+cannot+accurately+determine+which+files+belong+to+it+which+would+lead+to+only+a+partial+uninstall

Comment: Be careful about how you're using pip, take a look at https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up upgrading my llvmlite package which seemed to do the trick. Did not get to try the other posted solution but it may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with pip, try upgrading it with:

> pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Sorry I ended up upgrading llvmlite package which worked and did not get to try your answer.